hx-trigger="change" on input type="date" submits on every key press
The following code segment does not behave as I'd expect it to:
  <form hx-post="" hx-trigger="change">
    <input type="date" value="2024-05-02" />
  </form>         

I would expect: the user enters a new date and then htmx submits a POST request when the user changes the focus away from the field.
However, unfortunately, hx-trigger fires upon every key press. As soon as the user changes the day, there's already a post request, making the field unusable.
I did some more research and figured out that this is the standard behaviour of the onchange event on date fields. Here is a discussion for JS/jQuery: HTML5 <input type=“date”> - onChange Event.
How would you recommend to implement htmx form submission on date fields?

An input[type="date"] triggers a change event on every keypress if the current value is valid. Have you considered throttling/debouncing it?

Thank you for clarifying that this is the desired behaviour. I have a hard time understanding why. Why would change events behave differently for a date inputs than for text inputs? Why would we want 8 triggers upon typing a single date?
What is your recommendation on how to handle this? I don't much like to work with delays, because some users interact with the UI much faster than others. What do you mean with debouncing? Is this something I would do on the backend? How would I know on the backend if the user is done typing the date?

I mean like the delay/throttle built into hx-trigger; if you have to figure it out on the backend the request has already been sent. Or trigger the POST request on form submit.

Why don't you trigger on blur (of the date input) instead? It seems easier that way.

@McPherson: Changing my code example above to hx-trigger="blur" does not work. Is "blur" a valid attribute for hx-trigger? I can't find it in the doc: https://htmx.org/attributes/hx-trigger/

@jonrsharpe2: I use this field as part of a dynamic form that changes depending on the input on the date field. If I go with delays, it depends on the users speed. Some users are slow and then the form would reload before they finished the field. Other users are fast and would have progressed to the next entry field when the form gets swapped. Yes, of course, I could use a submit button instead, but that's not the UI I want and all other fields trigger on change.
